# Secondary hard drive disappeared after executing npm install, Windows 10 WSL

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, hard-drive, windows-subsystem-for-linux, npm

Normally I am developing my apps under C:, which is a SSD. This time, because I expected the node_modules folder to be huge, I decided to use my secondary hard drive (D:, 2TB).
After cloning the repo, I used Ubuntu (Windows Subsystem for Linux) to run **npm install**

I took a while, and a coffee later, my hard drive completely disappeared. It's not showing up in the disk manager, the device manager and not even in the BIOS.
I can't find words for what just happened, what can possibly go wrong when installing my dependencies that a whole hard drive is corrupted?

I can imagine that it has something to do with the fact that I am using WSL and how it handles paths, but that's just a wild guess.
I would be more than thankful if someone could help me out of this mess, as I don't have a backup of everything *important* on that disk.

What can I do to somehow restore my disk?

Some Details:

- My machine is an Asus Gaming Laptop (Asus GL503VM)
- Running Windows 10 Home (Version 1903, OS build 18362.356)

Comment: WSL would not affect the status of a drive mounted in Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that WSL is capable of killing the drive so thoroughly that it cannot
even be detected by the BIOS. It seems much more likely that some event caused
a hardware failure on the disk, perhaps an electrical surge or just a defective
disk.

I suggest to test the disk with another computer or inside an external enclosure
to test if the problem is with the disk or with your motherboard.
If the disk does not work under all conditions, it is dead.

If the disk is new and under warranty, asking for it to be replaced might be
the best course.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will now unmount it and try it with another computer. It's still under warranty, so in the worst case I can ask for a replacement.